# What is meant by an attribute of a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, noreturn

What this C++11 syntax means?

```
[[ noreturn ]] void f () {
    throw "error";
}
```

The C++ Standard Working Draft n3797 states,

> The first declaration of a function shall specify the noreturn
>   attribute if any declaration of that function specifies the noreturn
>   attribute. If a function is declared with the `noreturn` attribute in
>   one translation unit and the same function is declared without the
>   noreturn attribute in another translation unit, the program is
>   ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

What is meant by an attribute of a function?

Comment: The attribute of the function is just the `[[noreturn]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function is defined by its name, its return type, and a list of formal parameters, along with their types. These items constitute the "interface" of the function: they are important to the caller of the function, because they define the way to invoke it.

Attributes, on the other hand, provide a way to tell the compiler additional things about the function that do not alter its interface. When the compiler knows that a function is

- An interrupt handler, or
- A pure function (i.e. with no side effects or references to state of any kind), or
- A function that returns twice (similar to `fork`), or
- A function that never returns, etc.

the compiler can optimize the code better, and provide additional warnings / silence unnecessary warnings.

For example, if you write

```
main() {
    f();
    g();
}
```

and `f()` is marked `noreturn`, the compiler will issue a warning about the call of `g()` being unreachable.

Comment: And conversely, `int foo() { f(); }` need *not* produce a warning that there is no `return` from a function with non-`void` return value.

Answer (score 4):

Attributes are a new feature in C++11. Compiler vendors have long offered vendor-specific extensions that allow you to annotate functions in some way or another, but now there is a standard mechanism. There aren't many actual attributes specified by the standard (only `noreturn` and `carries_dependency`), but the *mechanism* for annotating functions is standardized now at least.

That said, the `noreturn` attribute has non-trivial semantics: If a function declared with this attribute does actually return, the program has undefined behaviour. Compilers should (but don't have to) produce a diagnostic if they can tell that you are returning from a noreturn function. The attribute is valuable to allow optimizations and better diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

`[[noreturn]]` attribute is for silence warning.

```
#include <stdexcept>

[[noreturn]] void report_error()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("error");
}

int f(int x)
{
    if (x > 0) {
        return x;
    }
    report_error();
}

int main()
{
    f(1);
}
```

If no use `[[noreturn]]`, compiler output warning in `f()`: `warning: control may reach end of non-void function`.

Answer (score 1):

From GCC's documentation
"
The noreturn keyword tells the compiler to assume that function cannot return. It can then optimize without regard to what would happen if fatal ever did return. This makes slightly better code. More importantly, it helps avoid spurious warnings of uninitialized variables."